# Org-mode for emacs: python sessions

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, org-mode

Emacs 27
Python 3.6
Windows 10

I have an issue working with sessions that causes org-mode to fail exporting.
Here is an illustration as an org-mode ecxerpt:

```
#+begin_src python :session one :results file
   #return 'filename.png'   --- DNU in session mode
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(x)
    fig = plt.plot(x,y)
    filename = 'filename.png'
    plt.savefig(filename)

    filename
#+end_src

Inside same session:

#+begin_src python :session one :results value 
  z = -1
  z
#+end_src

Yet inside same session again:

#+begin_src python :session one :results value  
  z = z - 3  
  z
#+end_src
```

The issue is that if I run the first block code it works fine and I get the correct output,  but then when running following 2 block code, it causes org-mode to stall for ever - no error message.
However if I run only the last 2 block codes, everything works as expected.

Any lead on what could be causing the problem would really be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my finding and solving.
The issue seems to reside in matplotlib that needs to use the 'Agg' backend.

Org-mode code would look like:

```
#+begin_src python :session one :exports results  :results file
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib
  matplotlib.use('Agg')
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
  y = np.sin(x)
  fig = plt.plot(x,y, color='red')
  filename = 'filename.png'
  plt.savefig(filename)    
  filename
#+end_src
```

Now, continuing on the same `:session one`:

```
#+begin_src python :session one :exports results
  f'The last value of x is: {x[-1]}'
#+end_src
```

Produces the desired results. Hoping someone will find this helpful.
Thanks